# Why is my website running fine on my computer but not on other's?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, netlify

I made a Spotify web app and launched it with Netlify. When I run its server file, it works well on my computer but not on my friend's. I thought it was because of the Spotify API at first but another web app I made, which doesn't use any API, only works on my computer as well. I think it's because of the server port or something but I'm not sure how to fix it.
Here's the website url and the server side code.

https://xenodochial-kepler-118793.netlify.app

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
const port = 4000 || process.env.PORT;

require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Create the api object with the credentials
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
});

// Retrieve an access token.
function newToken() {
  spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant().then(
    function (data) {
      console.log("The access token expires in " + data.body["expires_in"]);

      // Save the access token so that it's used in future calls
      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body["access_token"]);
    },
    function (err) {
      console.log("Something went wrong when retrieving an access token", err);
    }
  );
}

newToken();

tokenRefreshInterval = setInterval(newToken, 1000 * 60 * 60);

app.post("/search_result", (req, res) => {
  spotifyApi
    .searchArtists(req.body.keyword)
    .then(function (data) {
      let search_res = data.body.artists.items;
      res.json(search_res);
      res.end();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});

app.get("/albums/:id", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  spotifyApi
    .getArtistAlbums(req.params.id, { limit: 40 })
    .then(function (data) {
      res.json(data.body.items);
      res.end();
    });
});

app.get("/albums/tracks/:albumID", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.albumID);
  spotifyApi
    .getAlbumTracks(req.params.albumID, { limit: 20 })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data.body);
      res.json(data.body.items);
      res.end();
    });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`It's running on port ${port}`));
```

Main.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingerBox from "./SingerBox";
import axios from "axios";
import "../../App.css";

export class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      keyword: "",
      artists: [],
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ keyword: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.keyword === "") {
      alert("Enter Search Keyword");
    }
    axios
      .post(
        "/search_result",
        {
          keyword: this.state.keyword,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ artists: res.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="main">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label className="header" htmlFor="search">
              Explore New Artists
            </label>
            <span>
              <input
                className="search-box"
                type="search"
                value={this.state.keyword}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                name="keyword"
                placeholder="Search artists..."
              />

              <button className="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
                Search
              </button>
            </span>
          </form>
          <br />

          {this.state.artists.map((elem) => (
            <SingerBox images={elem.images} name={elem.name} id={elem.id} />
          ))}

          <br />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: What is the error your friend is seeing when he runs it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have hardcoded `localhost` in your code somewhere. The apis are hitting your local server when someone is searching for the artist.

[image]

Remove localhost from code and every thing should work fine.

Comment: I just removed it but now it gives an error "Request failed with status code 404".

Comment: Could you update the website that produces 404? I guess you misconfigured your frontend's backend URL.

Comment: I just edited it. I changed the url of the axios request in handleSubmit function from "http://localhost:4000/search_result" to "/search_result"